# Has anyone managed to find a Windows 7 RC x64 compatible driver for the Sony Firmware Extension Parser (SFEP) on the Sony Vaio VGN-NS20S/S?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, sony-vaio

**Problem**

- OS: Windows 7 RC x64
- Machine: Sony Vaio VGN-NS20S/S
- Missing Driver: Sony Firmware Extension Parser (SFEP) - sometimes known as SNY5001

I have tried various drivers for other versions of Windows and for similar laptops and searched online but they don't work. **Has anyone else managed to find one that *actually* works?** I'm not looking for advice on how to use Google :)

**Findings**

- [Sony Europe Support: SFEP_Driver_Sony_8.0_09Q1_O_8.0.0.1.zip](http://support.vaio.sony.eu/computing/vaio/downloads/preinstalled/index.aspx?l=en_GB&m=VGN-NS20S_S) for Vista, 32-bit - the closest official driver but sadly doesn't work on Windows 7 RC x64
- [Similar question on notebookreview.com](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=230565) but for the Sony Vaio VGN-AR570 on Vista x64. It gives some useful details about what the device does though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the *Action Center* again and this time the solution details contain instructions for users in Europe, not just the US and Brazil. I downloaded [the suggested file from Sony Europe](http://support.vaio.sony.eu/computing/vaio/downloads/info/info.aspx?l=en_GB&url=Vaio/Original/SFEP_Driver_Sony_8.0_09Q1_O_8.0.0.1.zip&m=VGN-NS20S_S&ip=Preinstalled_Drivers.htm) and updated the driver for my *Unknown Device*. It installed without errors and I now see *Sony Firmware Extension Parser Device* but it doesn't seem to have fixed the brightness shortcut keys. Interestingly the filename is the same as the one I tried before (`SFEP Driver (Sony) 8.0_09Q1_O - 8.0.0.1.zip`) only this time it definitely does include x64 drivers. Either I was going mad before and didn't notice them, or they've updated the package to include x64 drivers.

Comment: I realize this is 2 years too late, but if the question is still relevant, [this](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCCW27FXB&upd_id=5262&os_group_id=6) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect internet and do a Windows System Update? Windows 7 Should automatically find the driver for you

Ok I found this might help you as well [What can I do if my hardware doesn't work in Windows 7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/d4e80ccd-a9f8-4f4b-87c1-bdb9a3ca36a7) on technet forum

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't find anything. Windows does provide a link to a Sony website allegedly having suitable drivers but it doesn't have my model or country listed. I think the VGN-NS20S/S is UK/Europe specific and the site is US and Brazil only.